# Github, restricting third-party access to organizations

Tags: git, github, oauth, open-source

I use my Github account for both personal and professional projects. I'm a member of several Github "organizations" related to my professional life.

I'd like to start contributing to an open-source project in my free time, but the project requires me to sign a contribution agreement. The agreement is a Github application/bot that requires read-only access to my personal info (which is fine) but also admin access to my "repository webhooks and services."

The problem is, I don't feel comfortable allowing admin access of any kind to a third-party bot for the repositories belonging to my professional organizations. There doesn't seem to be a way to disallow access to my organizations without modifying the settings for *everyone* on the organizations themselves.

Is there any way around this besides maintaining separate Github accounts for my personal and professional identities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why this question was downvoted; maybe it's too specific to my needs. However, I contacted Github support and received this answer:

> GitHub does not have more granular permissions for third-party access
>   restrictions other than what is outlined here:
>
> https://help.github.com/articles/about-third-party-application-restrictions/
>
> As you mention, currently only the owner of an organization can enable
>   third-party access restrictions -- it isn't possible for a user to set
>   those restrictions when authorizing an app.
>
> However, this is definitely a feature that has been requested before.